# What is more natural for describing last night's actions, past simple or progressive?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

> — What did you do last night?
>
> — I watched YouTube. And what about you?
>
> — I met up with a friend and we watched a movie.
>
> — And what did you do before the meeting?
>
> — I roller-skated.

My textbook says that I should use the past progressive if I mention a precise moment (1pm, last night at 9:35, when she arrived). Like this "What were you doing last night at 5 pm", "What were you doing when it started to rain?", "What were you doing when father returned home?).
I wonder whether "last night" (without 9 pm) also counts as a precise moment and I can use the past simple and the past progressive interchangeably for the dialogue above.

> — What were you doing last night?
>
> — I was watching YouTube. And what about you?
>
> — I was meeting with a friend and we were watching a movie.
>
> — And what were you doing before the meeting?
>
> — I was roller-skating.

Something seems off for me in the second version.
I think it'b be better like this:
"I had met with a friend and we were watching a movie"

Comment: I agree. The continuous tense works fine except for 'I met a friend' which was not a continuing action.

Comment: @KateBunting do you like "I had met (up) with a friend and we were watching..."?

Comment: There's no reason to use the past perfect if you are just answering the question "What did you do last night?" If asked "What were you doing at 8.30 in the evening?" your answer would be fine.

Comment: @KateBunting okay, to avoid a misinterpretation: "I had met (up) with a friend and we were watching a movie TOGETHER"

Comment: The only reason you would ask *What were you doing last night?* rather than *What did you do last night?* would be if you were ***currently*** more interested in the ***time period*** of "last night" than in whatever the addressee was actually doing ***at that time***. Since this question mentions nothing about ***why*** the querent should be more interested in the time than the activity, there's no reason to suppose he'd use the pointlessly complex Past Progressive verb format.